# Can your employer take back HSA contributions?

Tags: united-states, hsa, healthcare, employment

Employer established a HSA and made a one time contribution of $750 per
employee and spouse or dependent for total of $1500. Can employer withdraw 
moneys from employee's HSA debit card account? Say if you drop a dependent
can they take back $750.
Thanks

Comment: Usually, you can only drop a dependent for specific reasons. Why are you dropping a dependent?

Comment: Just a guess here, but I don't think an employer can pull back the funds from your account unless it was deemed an error. I wouldn't call this an "error", but instead more like "changing their mind" once they have more information. So I would guess, no, they cannot take the money back from your account, but they could withhold the money from your future pay if they choose to.

Answer (score 2):

According to [this](https://www.insightbenefits.com/research/Current_Law_Rules_for_HSA_Plans.pdf) (page 3):

> **Excess and Erroneous Employer Contributions**. Whether an employer can recoup excess contributions made to an HSA depends on the facts.
>   If an employer makes contributions to an HSA on behalf of an
>   individual who was never HSA-eligible, then, yes, the employer can
>   correct the error and recoup any amounts contributed.

But as I had mentioned in my comments, you can only make changes in terms of add/dropping dependents under [specific circumstances](http://www.insure.com/health-insurance-faq/forced-to-keep-child-job-based-health-plan.html).

If you meet one of those criteria for dropping your dependent, then your employer probably won't deduct the $750 since it wasn't an error. It would be best to contact your HR department.